# How do I grab a specific router value?

Tags: javascript, angular

So when a post is clicked I do this which sends me to another page with the postId in the router:

`this.router.navigate(['/annotation', postId]);`

This navigates me to the annotations page where only that single post will be shown. In order for this to work, I need to get the postId which is now in the router link:

`http://localhost:4200/annotation/5b3f83b86633e59b673b4a4f`

How can I get that id: 5b3f83b86633e59b673b4a4f from the router and put it into my TS file. I want this id to only load posts with this ID.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to be able to grab the link `http://localhost:4200/annotation/5b3f83b86633e59b673b4a4f` take of everything and only get the ID at the end and store that in my TS file.

Sorry, I'm new to angular/web dev hence why I'm asking, many thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read params of activated route via `params` observable, subscribe on it and you will get access to route params:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'selector',
  template: ``,
})

export class LoanDetailsPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private paramsSubscription$: Subscription;

  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.paramsSubscription$ = this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
       console.log(params); // Full params object
       console.log(params.get('paramName')); // The value of "paramName" parameter
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.paramsSubscription$.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

PS: Don't forget to `unsubscribe()` in `OnDestroy` lifecycle hook.

Answer (score 1):

Try in the component which you load something like:

```
id: string;
ngOnInit() {
  this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('postId');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to inject the ActivatedRoute service and subscribe to the paramMap:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  // subscribe to the parameters observable
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
    this.foo = params.get('paramName');
  });
}
```